# Solr - How to get search result in specific format

Tags: json, solr, dataimporthandler

While exploring example for [indexing wikipedia data](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Example%3a_Indexing_wikipedia)
in Solr, how can we get the expected result (i.e. same as data imported)?

Is there any process that we can achieve it through configurations not from group query, because I have data which having lots of inner tags.

I explored xslt result transformation, but i am looking for json response.

imported doc:

```
<page>
<title>AccessibleComputing</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>10</id>
    <redirect title="Computer accessibility" />
    <revision>
    <id>381202555</id>
    <parentid>381200179</parentid>
    <timestamp>2010-08-26T22:38:36Z</timestamp>
    <contributor>
         <username>OlEnglish</username>
         <id>7181920</id>
    </contributor>
</revision>
</page>
```

solrConfig.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <document>
        <entity name="page"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                stream="true"
                forEach="/mediawiki/page/"
                url="data/enwiki-20130102-pages-articles.xml"
                transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer"
                >
            <field column="id"        xpath="/mediawiki/page/id" />
            <field column="title"     xpath="/mediawiki/page/title" />
            <field column="revision"  xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/id" />
            <field column="user"      xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/contributor/username" />
            <field column="userId"    xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/contributor/id" />
            <field column="text"      xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/text" />
            <field column="timestamp" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/timestamp" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'" />
            <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^#REDIRECT .*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="text"/>
       </entity>
       </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Response by solr query:

```
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "10",
        "timestamp": "2010-08-26T17:08:36Z",
        "revision": 381202555,
        "titleText": "AccessibleComputing",
        "userId": 7181920,
        "user": "OlEnglish"
      }
    ]
  }
```

expected response:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "10",
        "timestamp": "2010-08-26T17:08:36Z",
        "revision": 381202555,
        "titleText": "AccessibleComputing",
        "contributor": [{
            "userId": 7181920,
            "user": "OlEnglish"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I think you cannot do that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584857/solr-documents-with-child-elements

Comment: thanks for reply, while searching I found that, we can modify the result using xslt but there is any way we can do it using queryResponseWriter? and is there any example of custom queryResponseWriter?

Comment: I think you can achieve this using a poly-field-type and a multi-valued field. Ploy field types are like `solr.CurrencyField`, which consists of two or more simple fields like `integer`, `string`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like the idea of using [XsltResponseWriter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter) (which can help int outputting the results in JSON as well), you can create your own `SearchComponent`, which will modify the output. When you use a custom `SearchComponent` you can apply different ResponseWriters to the output (xml, json, csv, xslt, etc.).

You can learn how to create a custom `SearchComponent` in [this article](http://sujitpal.blogspot.ru/2011/04/custom-solr-search-components-2-dev.html), for example.

To use `XsltResponseWriter`, add this code to `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="org.apache.solr.response.XSLTResponseWriter"/>
```

Add a `json.xsl` file to `conf/xslt` folder, which has transformation rules for your XML output (when you use `wt=xml` in your query), something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" media-type="application/json"/>

  <xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:text>{"response":{"docs":[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc"/>
    <xsl:text>]}}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>{"contributor": [{"userId": </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="userId"/><xsl:text>, "user": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="user"/><xsl:text>"}]}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you can get this response using a url like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=id:10&wt=xslt&tr=json.xsl
```

Comment: Is there any complex example of using XsltResponseWriter? I found examples which has very basic xslt format.

Comment: XSL Transformation is done for XML files. I don't see XML in your question to transform to json. Actually, this is a new question, which has no direct connection to Solr, it is better to ask a new question with [XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt) tag.

Comment: I am trying to implement XsltResponseWriter to achieve what i asked in my question, Actually my file having large set of data, I am able to convert it into solr doc style but while querying for search result i need the data same as the content of file i imported (i.e in above example "contributor" having sub fields). I appreciate your help and thanks for quick response.

Comment: added example, elaborate it to include all fields