# remove header from the reult of a solr query

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, solr

my code looks like this

```
username = 'user'
password = 'user'
url = 'http://di4301sw:8081/solr/metadone/select?fl=file.contenu&q=patient.ipp:3456&rows=14'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)) 
data = r.json()
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

and my result looks like this

```
{"responseHeader": {"status": 0, "QTime": 0, "params": {"q": "patient.ipp:3456", "fl": "file.contenu", "rows": "14"}}, "response": {"numFound": 14, "start": 0, "docs": [{"file.contenu": "Biochimie d'urgence Dr F. Beyerle, Dr L. Chardon, A. Varennes Tel Secr\u00e9tariat
```

i want the result to start from "file.contenu" i.e. i dont want the header
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Why is the header an issue?

Comment: i wanted to calculate the tfidf of the result, so it is not seeing it as a json file unless i manually delete the header then it works

Comment: i want a way of removing it automatically to prevent the manual removal, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr - How to get search result in specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307246/solr-how-to-get-search-result-in-specific-format)

Comment: You can use requests Event Hooks -http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks and manipulate the response content

Comment: Thanks so much i will check the two links and get back to you

Comment: Have you tried `omitHeader=true` in your request URL?

Comment: the links sent couldnt solve my problem but i learnt a lot from them. Really appreciate you guys

Comment: Matslindh sorry i just saw your comment, iwill try that now

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks so much, it did removed some parts of the header, the result looks like this now {"response": {"numFound": 831, "start": 0, "docs": [{ "file.contenu": .... i dont know if there is a way i can delete everything before the square bracket because it didnt fit into my tfidf algo unless i delete everything before the square bracket. Thank you once again

Comment: I'd just reassign that part in your python part before sending it to your tfidf algo.

Comment: @MatsLindh you mean like you did for the omitHeader, right?. I did that already but did not remove the rest but its ok thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

There is a URL parameter for this, called `omitHeader`.

From the [documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_3/common-query-parameters.html#omitheader-parameter):

> If set to true, this parameter excludes the header from the returned results.

Comment: Unfortunately the JSON object returned will sill have `{
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[` to start with this parameter. Gets the OP closer but not exactly what they want.

Comment: One shall use another URL parameter called "wt". If set to "wt=csv" the response will not contain anything but the fields requested. It will be not in JSON format but will have the least possible overhead. I have tested with solr 9.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

you should parse the response in order to get the desired result:

```
data_to_dump=data['response']['docs'][0]
```

hope this helps