# How to model children document in Solr

Tags: solr

I want to have in Solr children documents. I'm using SolrJ to index the documents and I use the method `addChildDocument`.

In my structure of data I would have a parent object like a parent and children objects and I thought in the begining about using multivalue fields, the problem it's that if I use multivalue I lose that the value X belongs to childX and the value Y belongs to childY.

When I have used the method `addChildDocument` and query Solr, it seems that they aren't really linked, Instance of there are complete isolate documents.

I want to store in the same collection for historical reasons "books" and "writers", they would be liks this:

```
{...,
bookName : aaaa,
pages : 222,
...
authors: [
 { author : bbbb,
   age : 33,
   ...
 },
 { author : ....
 }
]
}
```

I know that it's not possible to do this in Solr, but I don't know how to model this structure in Solr or I should do it in another way.

Comment: maybe this could help: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr documents with child elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584857/solr-documents-with-child-elements)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing with addChildDocument is correct approach to add child documents. At the end, solr maintains the relation and you need to have a field which can identify difference between parent and child. **Can you elaborate how you identified "it seems that they aren't really linked, Instance of there are complete isolate documents".**

Your indexing part is correct. Once indexed, you should (1+n) documents(parent + n children). The way you search is through block join query. [This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers) will help you to query for parent for a field value in child, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I was checking how they do queries. I'm not sure if it's going to work to me because I'm using Solr + Hue and I can't define the queries. Hue just takes data from Solr and does some graphs automatically. So, I can't tell it,, this document is a child and its content_type is XXXXX