# What is the Solr field type for storing JSON object?

Tags: json, solr

I want to store `Json` data as a value to an field, currently I have tried keeping that field type as `string` or `text`, which is fine but the Json is stored in string and hence the double quotes`(")` are escaped inside that, so what field type need to be kept for Json Object ?

Eg, suppose my field is `Thumbnail` and it should be stored and display as json object instead of string like below

```
"Thumbnail": {
              "Url":    "http://www.example.com/image/481989943",
              "Height": 125,
              "Width":  "100"
          }
```

Comment: In case that you want to query the fields of the JSON document, you may find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584857/solr-documents-with-child-elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store it as String. The issue you are facing - I assume - is when you want to return that JSON as structure within the Solr JSON response. By default Solr does not know that you want to **embed** the content rather than **present** it.

To tell it otherwise, try using a [**[json]** document transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_json_xml_) in your **fl** parameter.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreRafalovitch !! You assumed it perfectly... But I found the solution before you answered it... Anyways the perfect answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`String` type stores a word/sentence as an exact string without performing tokenization etc. Commonly useful for storing exact matches, e.g, for facetting.

`Text` typically performs `tokenization`, and secondary processing (such as lower-casing etc.). More of use when you want to match a word which is part of that a sentence.

With the text you can use tokenizers and filter made available by `solr` in order to create more useful token in order have proper search.

I would suggest to store it as the `text`.

It would be helpful for you to `tokenize` the data and can be helpful in the search as well.

Also as its a `Json`, it would be bigger in size and may grow bigger in size, so again can be helpful to be stored as `text` instead of `string`.